# How to import a menu in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

So I have a component on vue.js and I cant import it on the App.vue

Component:

```
<template>
  <h1> Hello</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
<div>
  <menu />
 
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Menu from './componentes/menu/Menu.vue';


export default {
  components: {
    'menu': Menu,
  }
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here? The menu doesnt load

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: is it `components/menu` or `componentes/menu`?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code. First, as pointed out in the comments by @Naren, is

> componentes

misspelled - should it be `components`?

Secondly, when I try to run your code I get

> The "menu" component has been registered but not used

However, if I rename the component to an arbitrary name, like `'arbitrary': Menu,`, and include that, `<arbitrary />`, it works perfectly.

Menu.vue

```
<template>
  <h1> Hello</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
<div>
  <arbitrary />
 
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Menu from './componentes/menu/Menu.vue';


export default {
  components: {
    'arbitrary': Menu,
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This was also what helped my problem, the main reason you can't pick menu, is because it's a HTML tag that you can't overrule.